# A logical condiditon in "with" operator doesn't work

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have this code:

```
  def edit(conn, params) do
    with m1 <- Repo.get(Model1, params["model1_id"]),
      m2 <- Repo.get(Model2, params["model2_id"]),
      !is_nil(m1) and !is_nil(m2)
    do
      # 1
      res = !is_nil(m1) and !is_nil(m2)
      IO.puts("***** res: #{res}")                              # ===> false

      IO.puts("***** m1: #{Kernel.inspect(m1)}")                # ===> prints a struct
      IO.puts("***** m1 is_nil: #{is_nil(m1)}")                 # ===> false

      IO.puts("***** m2: #{Kernel.inspect(m2)}")                # ===> nil
      IO.puts("***** m2 is_nil: #{is_nil(m2)}")                 # ===> true

    else
      #2
      _ -> raise ArgumentError, "not found"
    end
  end
```

The flow #1 gets executed even though `m2` is nil. How can it be? How to fix it?
Goal - ensure that m1 and m2 aren't nil and then execute the flow #1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The `with`

The `with` expression is used strictly for pattern matching. It is not a "chainable replacement" for `if-else` conditionals.

Basically the `with` will go through all your clauses and try to pattern match them to the left side of the `<-` arrow. It will only execute one of the *error* clauses when the first pattern match fails (doesn't match).

#### The issue with your code

Your third line in the `with` is `!is_nil(m1) and !is_nil(m2)`, which always successfully pattern matches even though the expression itself equals to `false`.

#### The fix

To make the code do what you actually want you should add a left side to the third line so that it is forced to pattern match:

```elixir
with m1 <- Repo.get(Model1, params["model1_id"]),
      m2 <- Repo.get(Model2, params["model2_id"]),
      {false, false} <- {is_nil(m1), is_nil(m2)} do
 ...
```

#### Idiomatic Elixir

To make the code a bit more idiomatic Elixir, you can also use [Guards](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/guards.html), which `is_nil` is allowed as.
This would make your code look like:

```elixir
with m1 when not is_nil(m1) <- Repo.get(Model1, params["model1_id"]),
      m2 when not is_nil(m2) <- Repo.get(Model2, params["model2_id"]) do
 ...
```

#### Even better readability

One last tip would be to always focus on readability. You are writing your code for humans to read, so less stuff happening on a line is usually easier to read.

Your code would be even more readable as:

```elixir
m1 = Repo.get(Model1, params["model1_id"])
m2 = Repo.get(Model2, params["model2_id"])

with m1 when not is_nil(m1) <- m1,
      m2 when not is_nil(m2) <- m2 do
 ...
```

#### Do you actually need a `with` ?

Your `with` is doing nothing except making sure `m1` and `m2` are not `nil`. This can easily be done with a `case` or `if` as well, since you don't actually need any pattern matching here:

```elixir
m1 = Repo.get(Model1, params["model1_id"])
m2 = Repo.get(Model2, params["model2_id"])

if !is_nil(m1) && !is_nil(m2) do
 ...
```

Comment: Good answer but I don't get the tuple on `{true, true} <- is_nil(m1) and is_nil(m2)`. Shouldn't be `true <- is_nil(m1) and is_nil(m2)` or `{true, true} <- {is_nil(m1), is_nil(m2)}`?

Comment: Yep, very good catch @julp! Updated the example. Also, it should have been `{false, false}` since we don't want the "models" to be nil. Thanks <3

Comment: Thanks @T. Fartek, right, I was afraid to miss something as I read Q/A about Elixir to learn it ;)

Answer (score 2):

[`Kernel.SpecialtForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#with/1) “early returns” if and only there was no match in the clause.

In the third clause, you have `!is_nil(m1) and !is_nil(m2)` which roughly means `_ <- !is_nil(m1) and !is_nil(m2)` and it matches no matter what. To achieve what you want you need to explicitly use proper `with` clause with `<-`:

```rb
with m1 <- Repo.get(Model1, params["model1_id"]),
     m2 <- Repo.get(Model2, params["model2_id"]),
     true <- !is_nil(m1) and !is_nil(m2), do: ...
```

More natural would be to use proper guards to early return errors:

```rb
with m1 when not is_nil(m1) <- Repo.get(Model1, params["model1_id"]),
     m2 when not is_nil(m2) <- Repo.get(Model2, params["model2_id"]),
       do: ...
```

In fact, you don’t need `with/1` here. This would do perfectly (thanks for `nil` being `falsey`):

```rb
if Repo.get(Model1, params["model1_id"]) &&
   Repo.get(Model2, params["model2_id"]), do: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I find myself using `with` only in specific situations, and in those it really helps, mostly when it's some set of operations that resemble a "pipe", as in, you need results from previous steps in the next one, but are really heterogeneous and you don't have or doesn't make sense to create some token structure to hold transformations and error (similar to an ecto changeset).

In those cases, if knowing the failing step is needed I find wrapping the `with` statements on a tagged tuple helps, since then you can match on the specific tag having failed. Besides that, you aren't really using idiomatic code because you're using `with` just as an assignment expression, if you use pattern matching then it becomes more readable and in my opinion more idiomatic. With your example that would mean:

```elixir
with {_, %Model1{} = m1} <- {Model1, Repo.get(Model1, params["model1_id"])},
     {_, %Model2{} = m2} <- {Model2, Repo.get(Model2, params["model2_id"])}
       do
          # we have both m1 and m2 and they are respectively instances of Model1 and Model2
          # do something with them
          {:ok, {m1, m2}}
else
     {Model1, _} -> 
            #failed fetching Model1
            {:error, :no_model1}
     {Model2, _} ->
            #failed fetching Model2
            {:error, :no_model2}
end
```

Pattern matching on exactly the structure you want, and knowing that Repo.get will return either a schema struct or nil, makes it so that you don't have to check if it's nil, if it's not the schema struct it will be nil (unless you're using Repo.get with a select clause where you return something else ofc).

Remember that accessing `params["some_key"]` might return `nil` and that would throw an exception when trying to do `Repo.get`, so you could add two more statements with the conditions for the id and also enabling you to return the id's in case they weren't found, assuming that the id's are numerical ids (if binary change the `is_integer` to `is_binary`):

```elixir
with {_, id1} when is_integer(id1) <- {:id1, Map.get(params, "model1_id")},
     {_, id2} when is_integer(id2) <- {:id2, Map.get(params, "model2_id")},
     {_, _, %Model1{} = m1} <- {Model1, id1, Repo.get(Model1, id1)},
     {_, _, %Model2{} = m2} <- {Model2, id2, Repo.get(Model2, id2)}
       do
          # we have both m1 and m2 and they are respectively instances of Model1 and Model2
          # do something with them
          {:ok, {m1, m2}}
else
     {id_type, id_value} when id_type in [:id1, :id2] ->
            # one of the id params wasn't an integer
            {:error, {:unexpected_id, id_type, id_value}}
     {Model1, id, _} -> 
            # failed fetching Model1
            {:error, {:no_model1, id}}
     {Model2, id, _} ->
            # failed fetching Model2
            {:error, {:no_model2, id}}
end
```

There's probably some better handling of the params to be done, like verifying them before reaching this stage in execution, and if that is done then you could probably go with a `case` statement since it's only 2 "cases":

```elixir
case Repo.get(Model1, valid_id_1) do
    %Model1{} = model1 ->

       case Repo.get(Model2, valid_id_2) do
           %Model2{} = model2 -> {:ok, {model1, model2}}
           nil -> {:error, {:no_model2, valid_id_2}}
       end

    nil -> {:error, {:no_model1, valid_id_1}}
end
```